# How to delete item from RecycleView when that recycle is on Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to delete one Item from my RecyclerView with OnDeleteData.
but i have an error on Adapter file. (if i use this method for Activity its fine , but i change my activity to fragments)

Adapter File :

```
public class menuUserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<menuUserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public interface dataListener{
    void onDeleteData(Transaksi transaksi , int position);
}
dataListener listener;

public menuUserAdapter(ArrayList<Transaksi> listtransaksi, Context context) {
    this.listtransaksi = listtransaksi;
    //this.listuser = listuser;
    this.context = context;
    listener = (homeFragment) context;
}
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   holder.listitem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
       public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
          listener.onDeleteData(listtransaksi.get(position),position);
        }
   };
 }
}
```

on Fragments file :

```
  public class homeFragment extends Fragment implements menuUserAdapter.dataListener {


public void onDeleteData(Transaksi transaksi, int position) {
    if(reference != null){
        reference.child("transaksi").child(transaksi.getKey()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Berhasil Dihapus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
      }
  }


}
```

`listener = (homeFragment) context;`  i have erorr on this line

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your fragment is implementing the interface so initialize it with the fragment, context is the Activity context that holds the homeFragment.

```
public menuUserAdapter(ArrayList<Transaksi> listtransaksi, Context context, homeFragment fragment) {
    this.listtransaksi = listtransaksi;
    this.context = context;
    listener = fragment;
}
```

in your fragment

```
menuUserAdapter adapter = menuUserAdapter(listtransaksi, getActivity(), this);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: how to pass it to adapter ?

Comment: pass it via constructor like this menuUserAdapter adapter = new menuUserAdapter(listtransaksi, getActivity(), listener );

Comment: it still erorr , java.lang.ClassCastException : MyActivity cannot be cast to menuUserAdapter$dataListener

Comment: listener = (menuUserAdapter.dataListener) context; <<< eror at this line

Comment: How you are creating the menuUserAdapter object. Please paste that part..

Comment: You can't cast context to listener, Add one another parameter in your adapter.

public menuUserAdapter(ArrayList<Transaksi> listtransaksi, Context context, homeFragment  fragment) {
 listener =  fragment;

Comment: i found a new eror when i try that , dataListener cannot be converted to homeFragment

Comment: I have tested it on my side, its working fine please try it once.

Comment: adapter = new menuUserAdapter(listtransaksi, getActivity(),listener); erorr at this line, i can't run

Comment: forgot all that, just pass fragment instance to the adapter and initialize listener with fragment instance. answer updated have a look

Comment: like this 

menuUserAdapter adapter = menuUserAdapter(listtransaksi, getActivity(), this);

Comment: oohh God , finally.. ty mr Shamsul for helping me.. Ty very much GBU